# Crawling Jira with Manifoldcf and Solr - String index out of range

Tags: apache, solr, jira, manifoldcf

I am using Manifoldcf v2.7.1 and Solr v5.2.1 and trying to crawl Jira using the Jira connector and am getting the following error in Manifoldcf:

```
Error: Repeated service interruptions - failure processing document: 
Error from server at (servername:port/solr/jira): String index out of range: -11
```

*Note: I removed my server and port info from the error message*

One of the error logs from Solr is showing the following at the top of the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -11 
at org.apache.solr.request.macro.MacroExpander._expand(MacroExpander.java:144)
```

Don't know what is causing this area and how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there was a Jira issue with Java written in the comments section.  I think that it wasn't being exited out properly by Manifold.  To avoid this, I excluded this one issue that was causing issues from future crawls.